# Named export withRouter()

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I want to export the components `withRouter()` but I need it to be named without the default

```
export default withRouter(TopNav);
```

I've tried

```
export {TopNav} withRouter(TopNav);
```

The error I get from the linter is...

`Use of default exports is forbidden (no-default-export)tslint(1) is there a way name the export?`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Named exports have to be declared so you can do something like this:

```js
export const TopNavWithRouter = withRouter(TopNav);
```